# How can I create a file and its parent directories using a single method in Rust?

Tags: file, rust

Can I open a file creating it and its parent directories using `OpenOptions` or a similar single method?

This only creates a new file, it does not work if my path includes non-existing directories:

```
pub fn save_file(file_path: String) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut db_file = OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .append(true)
        .open(file_path)?;
    db_file.write_all(b"some content")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue but with my app using Tauri framework. What's strange is that in the development environment it is working but on a bundled app output (target release) it doesn't write the file.

Answer (score 33):

I couldn't find a *single* method to do this, but here's how to create the parent directory (etc.) for a given file in *two* (if you don't count `let path =`...).

```
let path = std::path::Path::new("/home/roger/foo/bar/baz.txt");
let prefix = path.parent().unwrap();
std::fs::create_dir_all(prefix).unwrap();
```

Comment: This could be subject to a TOCTOU attack and needs to be developed to be correct.

Comment: While your concern is correct, they didn't ask anything security related. Providing full blown solution that deals with every single case, that still contains this exact code somewhere, after some sanity checks, is completely pointless, they asked how to do it, and this is exactly how you do it, it's not our job to ensure that the code they write is actually safe, although I do agree that a mention of security related issues above or in the code would have been nice, that's why you can edit it as you deem fit, though :)

Comment: There seems to be no C here, just U. You always call `create_dir_all` unconditionally.

Comment: @Sahsahae I don't agree. If this code had a TOCTOU race condition, it would be wrong, regardless of any security concerns. A race condition of that kind is a bug. But the code simply doesn't have a race condition.

Comment: I'm trying to find the C here because I want to be sure I don't fall victim to the TOCTOU attack. As far as I can tell, @justinas is correct with this example, since the example is called unconditionally.